# many to many relation by Users and Files and ownership of it in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

How can I add ownership in many to many relationships?

For example like this models.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :editabilities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :files, through: :editabilities
end

class File < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :editabilities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :editabilities
end

class Editabilities < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :file
end
```

And I want to add a one-to-many relationship to User-and-Files.

At first I thought it is best to add `owner` boolean column to Editabilities, but I have no idea how to handle it.

Secondly I thought if I make a new junction model `Ownerships`, then I can handle it same way as `Editabilities`. But I've got a `uninitialized constant User::Ownership` when I tried it with code like this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :editabilities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ownerships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :files, through: :editabilities
  has_many :owned_files, through: :ownerships, source: :file
end

class File < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :editabilities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ownerships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :editabilities
  has_one :owner, through: :ownerships, source: :user
end

class Editabilities < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :file
end

class Ownerships < ActiveReord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :file
end
```

How can I implement a feature like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problems I see here are the classes `Editabilities` and `Ownerships`.  By Rails convention model class names should be singular, not plural.

```
class Editability < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :file
end

class Ownership < ActiveReord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :file
end
```

One way to quickly check your class names is by checking the result of the `classify` function:

```
> "editibilities".classify 
=> "Editibility" 

> "ownerships".classify
=> "Ownership"
```

The rest of the associations all look correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your class should be named `Ownership` and not `Ownerships`.
ActiveRecord class names are normally singular and table names are plural.

Easier solution seems to add belongs_to association to File model. Because 1 File can have only 1 owner.

```
class File < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
end
```

You will need to add owner_id column to files table.